# Execute/debug .jar file in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have a .jar file and I want to execute/debug it with Netbeans like I can do in IntelliJ. In IntelliJ it's possible to define a run configuration passing the parameters, like executing with java -jar parameters. It's possible to do this with Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run arbitrary classes from a jar file in NetBeans. You can only run classes that are part of your (current) project.

You would need to create a Java main class that calls the class you want to debug inside the jar file.

So if the class in the jar file is called `some.package.Main` you need to create a Java class:

```
package danyboy.debug;

public class RunIt
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
     some.package.Main.main(args);
  }
}
```

Then you can setup a [run configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/run_debug_japps.htm#NBDAG815) inside NetBeans to start `danyboy.debug.RunIt` and pass the necessary parameters.

I assume the jar file is already part of your project's class path.